# Why is this return type valid?

Tags: c++, vector, raytracing

I was having a look at the source code of this [raytracer](https://github.com/calmthatwombat/raytracer/blob/master/algebra3.cpp). On the file named `algebra3.cpp` at line 145 we can see this function:

```
inline vec2 operator * (const mat3& a, const vec2& v) {
    vec3 av;

    av.n[VX] = a.v[0].n[VX]*v.n[VX] + a.v[0].n[VY]*v.n[VY] + a.v[0].n[VZ];
    av.n[VY] = a.v[1].n[VX]*v.n[VX] + a.v[1].n[VY]*v.n[VY] + a.v[1].n[VZ];
    av.n[VZ] = a.v[2].n[VX]*v.n[VX] + a.v[2].n[VY]*v.n[VY] + a.v[2].n[VZ];
    return av;
}
```

It should return a `vec2` object instead its returning a `vec3`. Why is that?

Comment: The source code at the top states: `A vector of one dimension (2d, 3d, or 4d) can be cast to a vector
  of a higher or lower dimension.  If casting to a higher dimension,
  the new component is set by default to 1.0, unless a value is
  specified:
     vec3 a(1.0, 2.0, 3.0 );
     vec4 b( a, 4.0 );       // now b == {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
  When casting to a lower dimension, the vector is homogenized in
  the lower dimension.  E.g., if a 4d {X,Y,Z,W} is cast to 3d, the
  resulting vector is {X/W, Y/W, Z/W}.  It is up to the user to 
  insure the fourth component is not zero before casting.
`

Comment: It states that the vectors can be cast to different types of higher/lower dimensions

Comment: Might be an error, might be on purpose. Seems like the Compiler converts from vec3 to vec2.

Comment: Or they could be of some sort of a class hierarchy, and a vec2 would be the parent class of a vec3, which would allow this kind of conversion.

Comment: I see, the version I am reading does not have any comments since I downloaded from another page I cant remember anymore but the functions were almost identical so I linked that one.

Comment: It is returning a `vec2` object and it should be returning a `vec2` object. It's constructing the `vec2` it returns from a `vec3` -- do you have some reason to think that's incorrect?

Comment: Probably you are right n.m. But he is not discarding it though. If I am not mistaken the conversion goes something like `x/z and y/z` for the new `vec2` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `vec3` is implicitly convertible to `vec2`, then the function correct as far as the compiler knows.

It would seem silly to throw away `av.n[VZ]` right after calculating it. If that's what the program does, then I'm going to guess that it could be a programmer mistake.

Without more information about what the function is supposed to do, it's impossible to tell whether it should actually return a `vec3`, or whether the extra calculation is simply dead code left over and the temporary should be of type `vec2`. Or whether the current code is exactly what the programmer intended.